# how do i find what's going wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for my sql javascript

```
PATH="http://localhost/dhodia/";    
try{
                var tags=url.replace(PATH,"");
                var spl=tags.split("/");
                if(spl[0]=="i"){
                    if(spl.length>=2 && spl[1]=="hdd"){

                    }
                    addtoopen($("#"+spl[1]+"opn").attr("jso"));
                    menu_action(spl[1],url)   
                }
            }catch(err){
                var  txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
                txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
                alert(txt);
            }
```

i found there is problem at replace statement
if i use url  as **"http://localhost/dhodia/i/hdd"** it will do replace 
but if i use **"http://localhost/dhodia/i/hdd/tarun"** it is not doing replace

i want to track why it is not taking replace at this line

**EDIT**

I am using this in function as shown below

```
function hstppst(url){
    config.pre=url;
    if(url==PATH || url==PATH+"i/dashboard"){
        $E("#"+current.open).hide();
        unfixbox()
        $E("#dashboard").show();
        addtoopen(dsjsn);
        document.title="My DashBoard";
        current.open="dashboard";
    }else{
        var tags=url.replace(PATH,"");
        var spl=tags.split("/");
        if(spl[0]=="i"){
            if(spl.length>=2 && spl[1]=="hdd"){

            }
            addtoopen($("#"+spl[1]+"opn").attr("jso"));
            menu_action(spl[1],url)   
        }



    }     
}
```

and this function call when  `window.onpopstate` changes

in onpopstate i pass url to this function

problem is that code is not executing after `var tags=url.replace(PATH,"");` and because i am using this function in onpopstate function if any error occurs poage refreshed and i am track what is error i am getting.

Comment: see edit  Rocket and SimpleCoder

Comment: Oops.. Sorry about that @user1511547

Comment: What problem are you getting?  Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Fwxb7/

Comment: `"http://localhost/dhodia/i/hdd/tarun".replace("http://localhost/dhodia/","");` worksforme. How do you set the `url` variable?

Comment: yes i have tested this in simple test file it works there and in your jsfiddle also but this is though some kind of error that i want to track

Comment: @user1511547: What error?  What's the problem here?

Comment: page is refreshing when error occurs and i am not able to track it..firbug's console screen also clears when page refreshes

Comment: There is no code to refresh the page here.  The error is in either `addtoopen` or `menu_action`, not in this snippet.

Comment: wait a minute i update question

Comment: @user1511547 By the way Firebug has an option called 'Persist' that will allow you to see console logs after a page refresh.

Comment: @user1511547 If you are using the Firebug extension for Firefox, the console has a button labeled 'Persist', next to to 'Clear' button. Press it, it will keep your logs after a page load.

Comment: hey i found the problem. url is sedning as object

Comment: how do i convert it into string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the usage of replace method of the string object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

You mistakenly use replace.